# Calling Function in Verilog

Tags: function, verilog

When I called the function, it can not enter the `if` block , every time it can enter `else` block. And every time returns  `4'b1111` from function.
I try to print `[3:0] data`. It gives me "xxxx".
How can I fix this problem.

```
module workout(DATA1, OPCODE , OUTPUT);

input [7:0] DATA1;

input [3:0] OPCODE;

output reg [7:0] OUTPUT;

initial OUTPUT = func_call(DATA1);


function [3:0] func_call;
input [3:0]data;
begin

if(data[3:0] == 4'b0001)    
        func_call= 4'b0011;
else 
        func_call= 4'b1111;

endfunction
```

Comment: initial begin
  // Initialize Inputs
  DATA1 = 17;
  DATA2 = 3;
  OPCODE = 8;

  // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
  #100;
        
  // Add stimulus here

 end

Comment: A bit off topic, but is there a reason you are using non-ANSI coding style? ANSI style been the preferred coding style since simulators and synthesizers became IEEE1364-2001 complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using an `initial` block for something that should be assigned continuously.

`initial` blocks only start at time 0. Once the block finishes executing, it does not start again. `initial` are intended for initialization and test benches. FPGA do allow `initial` to be synthesized only for zero-time initialization purposes. IC do not support `initial` for synthesis (perfecting asynchronous resets instead).

`assign` statements are continuous. `always` blocks run forever but have time blockers statements (ex: `@*`, `@(posedge clock)`).

One option is to change `initial` to `always @*` or `always @(DATA1)`

```
always @* OUTPUT = func_call(DATA1);
```

Or make `OUTPUT` an wire type by dropping the `reg` and use an `assign` statement

```
output [7:0] OUTPUT;

assign OUTPUT = func_call(DATA1);
```

Also note that `DATA1` is 8-bits and `func_call` is expects an 4-bit input. Verilog will allow it but you should get warnings. It is better to specify the range of bits you want to use. Example: `func_call(DATA1[3:0])`